# Redirect after signout not working in Asp.net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using Asp.net Core 2.2 with AzureAD authentication. It works correctly, but now I'm having trouble trying to implement a log-out url.

I tried the following in my controller:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(AfterSignOut)) }, AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet("[action]")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult AfterSignOut()
{
    return Ok("It's working!");
}
```

When I go with the browser to `https://mySite/myController/SignOut` the log-out operation works correctly (my user gets signed out, and the next time I go to a page I have to sign-in again)

Hhowever, the problem is that **I am not redirected** to the `https://mySite/myController/AfterSignOut` url, as specified in the `AuthenticationProperties`. What happens instead is that `/SignOut` just returns HTTP code 200 and that's it, it doesn't redirect me anywhere.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried setting: `options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "your-after-sign-out-url"`on your `OpenIdConnectOptions` configuration?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but nothing happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below solutions if using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` and use authentication like :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

**Method 1:**

Create Account controller and write your own Sign Out action :

```
public readonly IOptionsMonitor<AzureADOptions> Options;
public AccountController(IOptionsMonitor<AzureADOptions> options)
{
    Options = options;
}
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    var options = Options.Get(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(AfterSignOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
        options.CookieSchemeName,
        options.OpenIdConnectSchemeName);
}
```

**Method 2 :**

Use exist Sign Out function from library , set your new redirect url in `OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect` event :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{

    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = (context) =>
    {

        context.Response.Redirect("/Account/AfterSignOut");
        context.HandleResponse();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

And in the page you want to perform sign out add a link :

```
<a href="~/AzureAD/Account/SignOut">SignOut</a>
```

**Method 3 :**

Use custom [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to redirect by checking the path , put below codes before `app.UseMvc`:

```
app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions().Add(
        context => { if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/AzureAD/Account/SignedOut")
            { context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/AfterSignOut"); }
        })
);
```

Also with link : `<a href="~/AzureAD/Account/SignOut">SignOut</a>`

Answer (score -2):

Try removing IActionResult and making it Void

```
public void SignOut()
{
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(AfterSignOut)) }, AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

OR

```
public async Task SignOut() // Not sure if it has a signout async method but use this if it does
    {
        return await SignOutAsync(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(AfterSignOut)) }, AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```